# Doctrine: How can I reference an attribute of a model with arrow ('->') notation?

Tags: php, doctrine

According to the Doctrine [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#columns) I should be able to reference an attribute of a model using either arrow notation (`$record->myField`) or array notation (`$record['myField']`) as long as the model is derived from the `Record` class.

I used Doctrine to generate my models from my database, so I have a (generated) `Recipe` class which extends a `BaseRecipe` class which extends `Doctrine_Record`.  After instantiating a `Recipe` object I can use the array notation to access its values, but using arrow notation just returns empty values.  What am I missing?

The BaseRecipe class which was generated by Doctrine has two methods:

```
public function setTableDefinition()
{
    $this->setTableName('rcp_recipe');
    $this->hasColumn('recipe_id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'fixed' => 0,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         'length' => '4',
         ));
    ...
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasMany('RcpTime', array(
         'local' => 'time_id',
         'foreign' => 'time_id'));
    ...
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to use it:

```
    $newRecipes = RecipeService::getLatestRecipes();
    foreach ($newRecipes as $recipe)
    {
        echo($recipe['title']); // prints the expected value
        echo($recipe->title); // prints empty string
    }
```

And here's my `getLatestRecipes` method:

```
static function getLatestRecipes() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Recipe')
        ->orderBy('recipe_id desc')
        ->limit(5);

    return $q->fetchArray();
}
```

Comment: Can we see code? Does BaseRecipe have a __construct() or BaseRecipe() method? No other error messages?

Comment: How are you instantiating the object?

Comment: @tilman: Added some code.  No error messages, just an empty string coming back.

Comment: *(sidenote)* [`->` is called `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return $q->fetchArray();
```

There's the problem ;)

Change that to

```
static function getLatestRecipes() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Recipe')
        ->orderBy('recipe_id desc')
        ->limit(5);

    return $q->execute();
}
```

And you will get an object, which enables you to use 'the arrow'.

You use [] to get properties from an array, and you use -> to get properties from an object. Since your method returns an array the -> doesn't work.

You should have gotten an error message though. ("Trying to get property from non-Object" or something like that)

Set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` while you are still developing.

Comment: If you just want the actual data of that query, I would suggest to use array hydration http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/data-hydrators/hu#core-hydration-methods:array